# How to easily experiment with elisp code that involves moving a cursor (caret)?

Tags: emacs, elisp, caret

I usually play with elisp code on my scratch buffer. I find it hard to play with elisp code that moves cursors in this way because I don't know how to separate the buffer for editing code and the buffer for testing the code.

For example if I want to play with the following code:

```
(backward-up-list 1)
(backward-sexp 1)
(kill-sexp 2)
```

from [searching with intelligent bracket counting elisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057314/searching-with-intelligent-bracket-counting-elisp), I'd like to run one line at a time and see what each line does. But the code moves the caret in the very scratch buffer I pasted that code in and I'm already using that caret to edit or run the code. Another problem is that this code is supposed to be tested on a TeX document and my scratch buffer is not a TeX document.

It all comes down to how to separate the painter and the painting.

Though in that example, just looking at the C-h f manual would be enough to understand what's going on. But that's only because this example code is simple enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compile the function with edebug (`C-u C-M-x` instead of `C-M-x`), switch to a buffer to experiment in, invoke the function via M-:, and then single-step (`n`) in the debugger.

Otherwise, learn to think in bigger chunks, and test in your test buffer with M-:.  This is what I do for nearly everything, including very complicated code like [cperl-mode](http://github.com/jrockway/cperl-mode).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `M-:` (i.e., eval-expression), also look at [`with-selected-window`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Selecting-Windows.html).  It executes its body in the context of a given window.  For example, assuming you have two windows,

```
(with-selected-window (next-window)
  (backward-up-list 1))
```

will perform the `backward-up-list` operation in the other window.

Answer (score 1):

I found some other workarounds (Similar to with-selected-window)

Using set-buffer with progn:

```
(progn
  (set-buffer "edithere.el")
  (insert "hello")
  (beginning-of-line))
```

The buffer name edithere.el must be present. Press C-M-x to evaluate the progn form. You can also use let. When you want to write a command that edits buffer or moves cursor, instead of starting with "(defun ...", you may start with "(progn ..." like above, and once it's finished, change to defun.

Using with-current-buffer: (Press C-M-x to evaluate the with-current-buffer form)

```
(with-current-buffer "edithere.el"
  (insert "hello")
  (beginning-of-line))
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>C-x 4 f</kbd>. Type a file name: `foo.el`. Put your code there, and test it there. Lot's better than the `*scratch*` buffer (Emacs-Lisp mode, for one thing), and you can more easily save your work.